# Confluent's Azure Blob Storage Source Connector: Restoring on a new topic

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-blob-storage, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to restore KAFKA messages from AzBlobStorage back on KAFKA but under a new topic, which I have already created manually (with the same number of partitions and replications). The problem: I cannot get the connector to post the messages on the new topic and instead it puts them back on the old one (which has the same name as the folder where the messages are stored). Here is a simplified version of my configuration:

```
name=src00002
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.azure.blob.storage.AzureBlobStorageSourceConnector
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://kafka-broker:29092
tasks.max=1
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1
azblob.account.key=
azblob.account.name=
azblob.container.name=kafka
topics.dir=test/
format.class=io.confluent.connect.cloud.storage.source.format.CloudStorageAvroFormat
topic.regex.list=restored_grant:.*
```

Any ideas/thoughts would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling with this for way too long by now.

Tried many versions of the regular expression but cannot make it write on the right topic.